# Android: When to register and unregister for notifications?

Tags: android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-adapter

I use a `Notifications` interface to update fragments whenever data is changed.

```
public interface Notifications {

    void register(ID id, Listener listener);
    void unregister(ID id, Listener listener);
    <T> void post(ID id, T value);

    interface Listener<T> {
        void onEvent(ID id, T value);
    }

    enum ID {
        CustomersUpdated,
        ProductsUpdated
    }

}
```

With regards to the [Android Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), what is the best point to register and unregister for notifications?

[image: Android Lifecycle]

Here are some scenarios:

## Scenario 1:

```
public class ProductsListFragment extends BaseFragment 
    implements Notifications.Listener {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        mAdapter.notifyDataChanged();
        register(Notifications.ID.ProductsUpdated, this)
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        unregister(Notifications.ID.ProductsUpdated, this)
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Notifications.ID id, Object value) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataChanged();
    }
```

## Scenario 2:

```
public class ProductsListFragment extends BaseFragment
    implements Notifications.Listener {

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mAdapter.notifyDataChanged();
        register(Notifications.ID.ProductsUpdated, this)
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        unregister(Notifications.ID.ProductsUpdated, this)
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Notifications.ID id, Object value) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataChanged();
    }
```

Please explain **why** you would suggest using one or the other implementation .. or another!

Comment: Why not register & unregister in you Application class?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a universal answer to this question. onResume/onPause will probably give the expected behaviour most of the time but you might run into cases where you want to do it earlier or later.

On a different note, though, two points on style and functionality - call `super.onResume` as the first thing in the method (and `super.onStop` as the last). That way your cycle is entirely nested inside the "super" cycle and you avoid weird bugs and edge cases. Further, it's not a great idea to always call `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onResume`. In fact, it's probably a pretty wasteful idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with Scenario 2. Although the order in which `onPause()` and `onResume()` is linear for fragments, the same is not true for Activities.

[image: fragment_lifecycle]

Since the fragments' pause and resume are called whenever the activity's is, broadcasts would be received whenever the activity is active. However, the activity does not call `onStop()` until it loses visibility. In this case, the fragments would still process broadcasts while the activity it is contained in is inactive, which doesn't sound like a very good idea to me.